# Why does my Resnet56 implementation have less accuracy than in the original paper?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, resnet

I was trying to implement Resnet56 in Tensorflow to classify the CIFAR10 images, but somehow I got a lower accuracy than the original creators.
I did everything exactly as described in the paper: same architecture, same data augmentation, same learning rate scheduling, same batch size...
But somehow my implementation produced an accuracy of only 91.84%, while in the original paper they reached 93.03% for the 56 layer Resnet.
Here is the link to the Resnet paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.03385.pdf
I found what my problem was (see answers if interested) and here you can find my (now correct) implementation, that can now reach the exact same accuracy:

```
import argparse
import datetime
import os
import re

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as keras
import tensorflow_addons as tfa
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

os.environ.setdefault("TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL", "2")  # Report only TF errors and warnings by default

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--resnet_n", default=9, type=int, help="n from Resnet paper.")
parser.add_argument("--seed", default=42, type=int, help="Random seed.")
parser.add_argument("--threads", default=1, type=int, help="Maximum number of threads to use.")


class ResNet(keras.Model):
    class ResidualBlock(tf.Module):
        def __init__(self, filters: int, down_sample: bool):
            super().__init__()
            self.filters = filters
            self.down_sample = down_sample

        def __call__(self, x):
            out = x

            out = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=self.filters,
                                      kernel_size=(3, 3),
                                      strides=(1, 1) if not self.down_sample else (2, 2),
                                      padding="same",
                                      use_bias=False,
                                      kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.HeNormal)(out)
            out = keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(out)
            out = keras.layers.ReLU()(out)

            out = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=self.filters,
                                      kernel_size=(3, 3),
                                      strides=(1, 1),
                                      padding="same",
                                      use_bias=False,
                                      kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.HeNormal)(out)
            out = keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(out)

            if self.down_sample:
                residual = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=self.filters, kernel_size=(1, 1), strides=(2, 2),
                                               padding="same",
                                               use_bias=False,
                                               kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.HeNormal)(x)
                residual = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(residual)
            else:
                residual = x

            out = out + residual
            out = keras.layers.ReLU()(out)
            return out

    def __init__(self, args):
        inputs = keras.layers.Input(shape=(32, 32, 3), dtype=tf.float32)
        outputs = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding="same", use_bias=False,
                                      kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.HeNormal)(
            inputs)
        outputs = keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(outputs)
        outputs = keras.layers.ReLU()(outputs)

        for _ in range(0, args.resnet_n):
            outputs = self.ResidualBlock(16, False)(outputs)

        outputs = self.ResidualBlock(32, True)(outputs)
        for _ in range(1, args.resnet_n):
            outputs = self.ResidualBlock(32, False)(outputs)

        outputs = self.ResidualBlock(64, True)(outputs)
        for _ in range(1, args.resnet_n):
            outputs = self.ResidualBlock(64, False)(outputs)

        outputs = keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(outputs)
        outputs = keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)(outputs)
        super().__init__(inputs, outputs)


def main(args, tb_callback):
    ds_train,ds_test = tfds.load("cifar10",split=["train","test"],as_supervised=True)

    img_augmentation = keras.Sequential(
        [
            keras.layers.RandomFlip("horizontal"),
            keras.layers.RandomTranslation(height_factor=0.125, width_factor=0.125, fill_mode="constant",
                                           fill_value=0.5)
        ]
    )
    ds_train = ds_train.map(lambda img, label: (tf.cast(img, tf.float32) / 255.0, label))
    ds_test = ds_test.map(lambda img, label: (tf.cast(img, tf.float32) / 255.0, label))

    total_count, per_pixel_sum = ds_train.reduce((np.float32(0), tf.zeros((32, 32, 3))),
                                                 lambda prev, curr: (prev[0] + 1.0, prev[1] + curr[0]))
    per_pixel_mean = per_pixel_sum / total_count

    ds_train = ds_train.map(lambda img, label: (img_augmentation(img, training=True), tf.one_hot(label, 10)))
    ds_test = ds_test.map(lambda img, label: (img, tf.one_hot(label, 10)))

    ds_train = ds_train.map(lambda img, label: (img - per_pixel_mean, label))
    ds_test = ds_test.map(lambda img, label: (img - per_pixel_mean, label))

    ds_train = ds_train.shuffle(5000).batch(128, drop_remainder=True).prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
    ds_test = ds_test.shuffle(5000).batch(128, drop_remainder=True).prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

    model = ResNet(args)

    learning_rate = keras.optimizers.schedules.PiecewiseConstantDecay(
        [32000, 48000], [0.1, 0.01, 0.001]
    )
    weight_decay = keras.optimizers.schedules.PiecewiseConstantDecay(
        [32000, 48000], [1e-4, 1e-5, 1e-6]
    )

    model.compile(
        optimizer=tfa.optimizers.SGDW(weight_decay=weight_decay, learning_rate=learning_rate, momentum=0.9,
                                      nesterov=False),
        loss=tf.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
        metrics=[tf.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy("accuracy")],
    )

    model.fit(x=ds_train, epochs=200, validation_data=ds_test, callbacks=[tb_callback], use_multiprocessing=True,
              workers=args.threads)

    model.save(args.logdir + '/model')
    print('OK')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = parser.parse_args([] if "__file__" not in globals() else None)

    # Fix random seeds and threads
    np.random.seed(args.seed)
    tf.random.set_seed(args.seed)
    tf.config.threading.set_inter_op_parallelism_threads(args.threads)
    tf.config.threading.set_intra_op_parallelism_threads(args.threads)

    # Create logdir name
    args.logdir = os.path.join("{}/{}".format("logs", os.path.basename(globals().get("__file__", "notebook"))),
                               "{}-{}".format(
                                   datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S"),
                                   ",".join(("{}={}".format(re.sub("(.)[^_]*_?", r"\1", key), value) for key, value in
                                             sorted(vars(args).items())))
                               ))

    tb_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(args.logdir, histogram_freq=1, update_freq=100, profile_batch=0)

    main(args, tb_callback)
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to the paper?

Comment: Sure, question updated

Comment: A difference between an accuracy of 91.84% and one of 93.03% is not necessarily significant and it may be in the range of performance differences due to different random seeds. Did you try to run the model with (several...) different random seeds? If yes, what were the results?

Comment: For what it's worth, after reading the paper, I don't think you made any mistakes in the implementation of the model. I agree with desertnaut, I think you should try more seeds if at all possible

Comment: Yes, more seeds produced similar results, I had some real bugs, posted as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what my problems were:

- I didn't apply data augmentation correctly, changed `img_augmentation(img)` to `img_augmentation(img, training=True)`
- Changed kernel initializer to HeNormal, what they used in the paper
- Added per pixel mean substraction as a normalization
- Disabling nesterov helped somehow (IDK why)